# ng-pattern regex to allow all characters except decimal value

Tags: regex, angularjs

I have come up with the following `regex` sample to allow everything from keybaord except float(decimal value) `e.g. .1, 0.1, 1.1, 1.1., 1.1.1 etc`

```
ng-pattern="/^[\w -!@#$%^&\*()\+]*$/" />
```

Is there a short way to write regex for my requirement i.e. Allow everything from keyboard except loat(decimal value) e.g. 0.1, 1.1, 1.1. etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead based regex.

```
^(?!\d*\.\d+$).*
```

`(?!...)` called negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by the text which was matched by the pattern present inside the negative lookahead. So here, `^(?!\d+\.\d+$)` , it matches the start of the line boundary only if the start of the line boundary was not followed by a `\d+\.\d+$` decimal number.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nT9nL7/1)

Comment: it looks fine.can u bit explain it? would be good for others to understand as well how it works.

Comment: it accept/match .1 as well. It shouldn't accept it. I just updated my question as well. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Well i got it working with minor change ^(?!\d*\.\d+$).* What you say?

Comment: probably the last thing .. it also match 1.1.1 whereas it shouldn't. So, can you update you answer? I meanwhile update my question

Comment: try `^(?!\d*(?:\.\d+)+$).*`

Comment: Thanks it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\w !@#$%^&\*()\+-]*$

    ^^            ^^
```

Your regular expression cannot accept `decimals` as it cannot match `.`.You need to place `-` at the `end` or `escape` it/